# unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm using the latest ECS Agent v1.22.0 for Windows ECS cluster. I want to try out the new feature https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html?shortFooter=true but with the following failed error message:

```
service XXX was unable to place a task because no container instance met
all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance YYY is
missing an attribute required by your task.
```

It doesn't appear ECS Agent logs show any error. My Task has the following attributes:

```json
"requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.28"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.secrets.ssm.environment-variables"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

fwiw the windows instructions seem to include a gotcha here:

> For Windows tasks that are configured to use the awslogs logging driver, you must also set the ECS_ENABLE_AWSLOGS_EXECUTIONROLE_OVERRIDE environment variable on your container instance. This can be done with User Data using the following syntax:

see [the instructions here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html)